# SSHD AllowGroups, controlling access by groups

Tags: linux, security, sshd

I am having an issue with SSHD on ubuntu.  I am attempting to provide more robust security on an SSH server by using `AllowGroups` to restrict accounts that can log on remotely.  Unfortunately, it appears that users NOT in the Allowed Group can still login and issue commands.

I am using:
OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

I have added the following lines to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
AllowGroups ssh

DenyGroups *
```

I have two user accounts created

```
$ id test1
uid=1002(test1) gid=1003(test1) groups=1003(test1),113(ssh)
$ id test2
uid=1003(test2) gid=1004(test2) groups=1004(test2)
```

user test2 can still ssh from a remote terminal.

When I test the `sshd` server configuration it appears to include the `AllowGroups` setting of group `ssh`

---

```
$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -T

port 22
protocol 2
addressfamily any
listenaddress 0.0.0.0:22
listenaddress [::]:22
usepam 1
serverkeybits 1024
logingracetime 120
keyregenerationinterval 3600
x11displayoffset 10
maxauthtries 6
maxsessions 10
clientaliveinterval 0
clientalivecountmax 3
permitrootlogin without-password
ignorerhosts yes
ignoreuserknownhosts no
rhostsrsaauthentication no
hostbasedauthentication no
hostbasedusesnamefrompacketonly no
rsaauthentication yes
pubkeyauthentication yes
kerberosauthentication no
kerberosorlocalpasswd yes
kerberosticketcleanup yes
gssapiauthentication no
gssapikeyexchange no
gssapicleanupcredentials yes
gssapistrictacceptorcheck yes
gssapistorecredentialsonrekey no
passwordauthentication yes
kbdinteractiveauthentication no
challengeresponseauthentication no
printmotd no
printlastlog yes
x11forwarding yes
x11uselocalhost yes
permittty yes
strictmodes yes
tcpkeepalive yes
permitemptypasswords no
permituserenvironment no
uselogin no
compression delayed
gatewayports no
usedns yes
allowtcpforwarding yes
useprivilegeseparation yes
pidfile /var/run/sshd.pid
xauthlocation /usr/bin/xauth
ciphers 3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com
macs hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-md5,hmac-md5-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com
versionaddendum 
kexalgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
loglevel INFO
syslogfacility AUTH
authorizedkeysfile .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
hostkey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
allowgroups ssh
denygroups
acceptenv LANG
acceptenv LC_*
authenticationmethods
subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
maxstartups 10:30:100
permittunnel no
ipqos lowdelay throughput
rekeylimit 0 0
permitopen any
```

---

Am I incorrect in my understanding of the function of `AllowGroups`?  Do I have a conflicting setting?  Does anyone have an example of a working `sshd_config` with `AllowGroups` that I study?  Thanks.

Comment: where did you find that `DenyGroup` accepts `*` wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

You may accomplish the same with PAM module pam_listfile.

```
auth    required       pam_listfile.so \
        onerr=fail item=group sense=allow file=/etc/logingroups
```

It means that only the groups listed in /etc/logingroups will be allowed to authenticate in the server.
Check its man page: http://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_listfile